# What's the most likely mass for ethanol?

Tags: mass, atomic-physics, mass-energy, molecules, binding-energy

I am interested in learning a little about mass defect and calculating the molar mass of ethyl alcohol.

I found this [table of atomic weights](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/Compositions/stand_alone.pl) and would like to use it to compute the mass of the average ethyl alcohol molecule. How wrong is it to simply say

$$m_{\text{C}_2\text{H}_5 \text{O}\text{H}}=2m_{\text{C}}+6m_{\text{H}}+m_{\text{O}}.
$$

How does binding energy affect the mass of one molecule? Can I argue like this:
We start with one molecule of ethyl alcohol with mass $m_{\text{molecule}}$. Now, we "tear apart" a hydrogen atom from it. Let the Energy required to do that be $E_1.$ We keep doing this until we have 9 isolated atoms. Let's say the total energy required to do that was $\Delta E = \sum_i E_i$. Can I now say

$$
m_{\text{molecule}}=m_{\text{isolated}}+\frac{\Delta E}{c^2} ?
$$

Comment: In general, molecular binding energies are at the order of 0.1--10 eV, while the mass ot the nuclei/atoms is in the order of 1--10 GeV/$c^2$ So we're talking about mass deficiencies about 10 orders of magnitude smaller than the mass of the molecule.

Comment: @AndréasSundström Do you have a source for me?

Comment: Your plus sign should be a minus: molecule is slightly lighter, not heavier, than sum if weights of atoms.

Comment: *Do you have a source for me?* Look up 'Heat of Formation' (of chemical compounds)

Comment: @ty. Well I'm no chemist, but as Gert said, you can have a look at the [enthalpy of formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_of_formation) for the energy released when forming a molecule from free atoms. Then the mass of the nuclei/atoms is some approximate integer multiple of the [proton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton) mass, which is 0.938 GeV/$c^2$.